# Spring Data Mongo: prevent save operation on BeforeSaveEvent

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Here is my problem: I have to make some low level uniqueness check before document is saved into Mongo. I want to prevent saving the document if the uniqueness check failed.

I decided to make use of `AbstractMongoEventListener.onBeforeSave()`.

I was thinking of something like the following:

```
class MyEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<User> {

    @Autowired
    UserEmailRepository userEmailRepository;

    @Override
    public void onBeforeSave(BeforeSaveEvent<User> event) {
        User user = event.getSource();
        try {
            UserEmail userEmail = new UserEmail(user.getEmail());
            userEmailRepository.insert(userEmail);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException ex) {
            //prevent from saving User document
        }

    }
}
```

but I'm having trouble with implementation of preventing of the save operation to process.

I can see 3 possibilities to accomplish my task:

1. block the save operation in catch block (if it's possible)
2. move the try/catch to the higher level
3. catch the exception in this listener, but then remove duplicated record in the AbstractMongoEventListener.onAfterSave()

Could you guys please give me some advice how to accomplish this task?

Comment: You already have three options? Why do you want more?

Comment: I don't know if first is even possible, the next two are in case the first one is impossible to do

Answer (score 2):

> block the save operation in catch block (if it's possible)

Yes. You can block by throwing an exception from your Listener. It will be working.

Referring to the others:

I assume that you have 2 different **@Documents** and before saving the **@Document User** you want to check if you can save **@Document UserEmail**.

You can:

- catch exception as you did and throw different one,
- or just avoid the catch block.

In both cases result is the same.
Neither UserEmail nor User @Documents are saved and exception is propagated.